# Delete just one field of a row of a mysql table in php

Tags: php, mysql

so here's my problem:

Imagine that I have a mysql table called friends with only two fields, name and phone number ( to keep things simple). I want to delete the record of the phone but keep the name of just one friend. I don't want to update it, I want to delete it - let's say he's got no phone anymore, but he's still my friend-. Is there any specific sentence to do that or I just have to delete the whole row and create a new one?

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: You are looking for an UPDATE statement.

Comment: UPDATE to what? To a blank space?

Comment: If that’s what you want the new value to be …

Comment: I want the new value to be nothing.

Comment: If you can re-structure the tables,one way would be to keep separate tables for your friend's names and phone numbers. That way, you can use the friend_id(Foreign key) to attach with the phone numbers. With that you remove the whole telephone info without losing your friend, since its in a separate table.

Comment: “Nothing” in databases usually is `NULL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't delete a column in a single row. You can delete the value in a column for a row or set of rows, or delete the entire column in which case all the data for other rows will be deleted too.

You probably want to do something like this:

```
UPDATE `myTable` SET `phone` = null WHERE `name` = 'Fred';
```

Comment: Looks like I'm famous, once again ;-) Immortalized in code. I'll bet you were counting on me to see this, eh Mike? lol

Comment: @Fred-ii- I can think of no better role model ;)

Comment: Now that alone is worth more than just a `+1` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just set the contact number field to null or empty

UPDATE `myTable` SET `phone` = null WHERE `name` = 'SomeName';

OR

UPDATE `myTable` SET `phone` = '' WHERE `name` = 'SomeName';

You don't need to delete the complete row.